# Rails 3 upgrade will_pagination wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, will-paginate

I am in the process of upgrading my rails app from 2.3.5 to 3.2.5 on ruby 1.9.3. In the old app I was using the will_paginate plugin, which I have converted to a gem.

Now after the upgrade I am getting the following error :
    wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

A few lines from application trace:
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
will_paginate (3.0.3) lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:124:in `paginate'
app/models/activity.rb:28:in `dashboard_activities'
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:10:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.5) l
```

I believe the issue is in the old code in the activity Model where I am using pagination. Can anyone help?

The code:

```
def dashboard_activities(page, total_records, date_range1 = nil, date_range2 = nil ) 
  unless date_range2.nil? 
    x =[ "is_delete = false AND status = 'open'  AND date(due_date) between ? and ?", date_range1, date_range2]
  else
    x =[ "is_delete = false AND status = 'open' AND date(due_date) = ? ", date_range1]  
  end       
  paginate(:all,
    :page =>page,
    :per_page =>total_records,
    :conditions => x,
    :order =>"due_date asc")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all:

the paginate method only expects one argument and that is the options hash.
If you leave out the :all argument all will work fine.

In the gem version >= 3.0 you can call the shorter page-method like this:

```
paginate(page: page, per_page: total_records, conditions: x, order: "due_date asc")
```

see the [will_paginate wiki](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) for further details.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestion. after making that change now I am getting this error
    NameError (undefined local variable or method `page' for         #<Class:0x3cb40f0>):

Comment: Then maybe you try it with the full method name "paginate" again. This does work!

Comment: Yes it does work with Paginate but not having ( :all) breaks other parts of the code which is in view - Files

Comment: but you do not need the :all anymore, because now you get all implicitly now. Can you provide the breaking parts in an update to your question.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the update.. I updated the gem version to 3.0.3 and removed :all the new code is                                          page( :page =>page,
               :per_page =>total_records,
               :conditions => x,
                 :order =>"due_date asc")
    end.. now the error message I am getting..Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 114ms

TypeError (can't convert Hash into Integer):
  app/models/activity.rb:31:in `dashboard_activities'
  app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:10:in `index'

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you post the calling Controller code that show what parameters you're sending to the model method. From here we can only guess, but it seems to be a problem, that you are handing the complete hash for one parameter, e.g. the page.